# Microsoft Access Database - Downloading ALL attachments from MULTIPLE entries

Tags: ms-access

I am currently trying to download many .doc files that are attached to the Microsoft Access record under the "Attachment" field which is labeled as "File/Attachment". However, I need the ability to run a query (Search By Loss Incident) which I did prior and then run the macro to download ALL the attachments from multiple records. This is my code below, I need some help with it! I am getting an error of "This expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments".

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function SaveAttachmentsTest(strPath As String, Optional strPattern As String = "*.*") As Long
Dim dbs As DAO.database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
Dim strFullPath As String

'Get the database, recordset, and attachment field
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Search By Loss Incident Name")
Set fld = rst("File/Attachment")

'Navigate through the table
Do While Not rst.EOF

'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
Set rsA = fld.Value

'Save all attachments in the field
Do While Not rsA.EOF
If rsA("FileName") Like strPattern Then
'To Export the data, use the line below
strFullPath = "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\Test" & "\" & rsA("FileName")

'Make sure the file does not exist and save
If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
rsA("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
End If

'Increment the number of files saved
SaveAttachmentsTest = SaveAttachmentsTest + 1
End If

'Next attachment
rsA.MoveNext
Loop
rsA.Close

'Next record
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
dbs.Close

Set fld = Nothing
Set rsA = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: This line of code causes a conflict: `SaveAttachmentsTest = SaveAttachmentsTest + 1`

Comment: Tested code, no error, runs fine. Have you step-debugged? Do you provide parameter for the strPath argument? Although it is not used in code it is required by the function.

Comment: When I get the error and try to debug, no line is given as an error. That's the problem. I can't figure out what's wrong. I'll try out all fixes you guys mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a *local variable*:

```
<snip>

    Dim SavedAttachments As Long

<snip>

    ' Increment the number of files saved.
    SaveAttachments = SaveAttachments + 1
End If

<snip>

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rsA = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

    ' Return the count of saved files.
    SaveAttachmentsTest = SaveAttachments

End Function
```

Comment: Hello Gustav! I appreciate the help with this question but it nothing is happenin when I run this. I'm not sure what is happening. Is the rest of the code correct overall? This is my process of work that I want it to work. 1) Upload Data using a form to the database 2) I run a query called "Search By Loss Incident" by using a common word and these lines have a .doc attached to them 3) I run the VBA code and it should download all the files from THAT query into a folder. I feel like I'm not anywhere close.

Comment: Don't know, but you did miss that variable, and still do. Also, include `Option Explicit` in the top of the module. Then compile and correct errors.

Comment: So, when I created the Query, it automatically asks for an input from the user when they double click the query. How do I go about implementing this into the code? I'm so lost, I've never really coded in Access VBA before tbh.

Comment: I updated my code by using QueryDef instead but now I'm getting a "Compile Error: Method or data member not found". Should I just create a new post with my updated code?

Comment: Yes, do that. And include the exact error and code line.